# Jquery Get request to sub domain

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a get request on example.com and I want to do a get request to foo.example.com

```
$.get("foo.example.com/helloworld.txt",function(){})
```

does not work for me

Comment: what does `does not work for me` mean? are you getting error? if so whats that error?

Comment: probably a cors error

Comment: I'm getting a 404 error but could you post the line that would work unless mine should have worked

Comment: Use an absolute path, not a relative one

Comment: @JohnSmith: the URL does not exist, of course it would return a HTTP 404 error. You can try yourself by inputting the URL into your web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the protocol (http or https) like

```
$.get("http://foo.example.com/helloworld.txt",function(){})
```

foo.example.com need to allow your access (if you are not on the same domain). See 
[CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) for details. In your case it should set a HTTP header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
```

This could be set with a server configuration (depends on the server you use) or by the server program, in case of a php program for example this can be done with

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com');
```

Comment: I learned that if I'm on https://example.com I can't connect to http://foo.example.com because it's an unsecured connection

Comment: ...unless foo.example.com sends a header which allows that: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com`

Comment: If the answer helped then please mark it as accepted. If anything is still open, then please tell.

Answer (score 0):

Try with absolute path

$.get("http://foo.example.com/helloworld.txt",function(){})

and helloworld.txt must be allowed by remotely.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://foo.example.com/helloworld.txt. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).